# How to enble quota option f2fs filesystem?

Tags: f2fs

I'm trying to use quota option in the f2fs filesystem.
I have created a filesystem with f2fs and have a mounting point.
I have added quota mounting options in /etc/fstab and remounted my device(sd card) and checked with the following command: `cat /proc/mounts | grep ' /mnt/xyz '` I cant see updated quota options in device mounting options.

my linux kernel is v5.11 and I found that quota option is available from linux kernel v5.14(https://www.ansymbol.com/linux/v5.14/ident/quota_ino).

> quotacheck: Mountpoint (or device) /media/venk/UserData not found or has no quota enabled.

> quotacheck: Cannot find filesystem to check or filesystem not mounted with quota option.

any solutions, please?

Comment: Please show the output from your `mount | grep`, and also the command(s) you used that generated the `quotacheck` responses

Comment: @roaima
command used:
`sudo quotacheck -ugm /media/venk/UserData`
I am able to do quota things on ext4 but not on f2fs.

Comment: @roaima 
formatted with mkfs.f2fs with quota and additional features for example encrypt,quota,etc enabled. Added quota mounting options in /etc/fstab, and remounted.  Then checked with the follwoing command: `sudo cat /proc/mounts | grep ' /media/venk/UserData'` /dev/sdb2 /media/venk/UserData f2fs rw,lazytime,relatime,background_gc=on,discard,no_heap,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,inline_dentry,flush_merge,extent_cache,mode=adaptive,active_logs=6,alloc_mode=reuse,fsync_mode=posix 0 0

Comment: Please put all that in your question where it belongs. Comments are for asking for details, not providing them. Make it easy for others to see your question in its entirety, not as little bitty bits

Answer (score 0):

Enabling quota options for an f2fs filesystem involves several steps:

1. Prerequisites:

   - Kernel support: Ensure your kernel version supports f2fs quotas. 
     You can check this by running `uname -r`
     and searching the kernel documentation for "f2fs quota."
   - Quota tools: Install the quota package. 
     On Debian/Ubuntu, use

     ```
     sudo apt install quota
     ```
   - Quota kernel module: Make sure the quota kernel module is loaded. 
     Run

     ```
     lsmod | grep quota
     ```

     If not loaded, load it with `sudo modprobe quota`.
2. Enable quotas at mount time:

   There are two ways to enable quotas:

   - Using fstab:

     1. Edit your `/etc/fstab` file.
     2. Find the line corresponding to your f2fs filesystem.
     3. Add the `usrquota` and `grpquota` options
        (or `prjquota` for project quotas) to the mount options. 
        For example:

        ```
        /dev/sdX1 /path/to/mountpoint f2fs defaults,usrquota,grpquota 0 0
        ```
     4. Save the file and remount the filesystem with

        ```
        sudo mount -o remount /path/to/mountpoint
        ```
   - Using the mount command:

     ```
     sudo mount -o usrquota,grpquota /dev/sdX1 /path/to/mountpoint
     ```
3. Enable quotas on users:

   After mounting with quotas,
   use the `quotacheck` command to enable quotas on users and groups:

   ```
   sudo quotacheck -ug /path/to/mountpoint
   ```
4. Set quota limits:

   Use the `quota` command
   to set specific quota limits for users or groups:

   ```
   sudo quota -u <username>  -b 10G /path/to/mountpoint
   sudo quota -g <groupname> -b 10G /path/to/mountpoint
   ```